# How to notify data set change on the Spinner

Tags: android

I have used Spinner for populating the ListView. Depending upon the Spinner value ListView gets populated. It's working fine. Now our Project requirement is when user clicks on delete Button that focus Spinner value has to be removed and ListView has to get refreshed. It is happening also.

I have used

```
adapterspinnerInvoiceNO.remove(Billnumber);
adapterspinnerInvoiceNO.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I side the `Onclicklistener` of the adapterspinnerInvoiceNO Listview get Populated.

I am stuck in one position. Suppose adapter contains Select, A and B element If I remove B then set Onclick listneer gets called and Listview with A element get populated. But If I remove A Set OnClick Listneer Will not get Called that's why my listview also not get populated. I don't know why it is giving  issue in 2 element.

Answer (score 0):

Try like the following.

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewbyId(R.id.spinner);
int position = mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
```